# White screen PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, screen

I always get a white screen when I go to the index.php of PhpMyAdmin. When I echo "Hello", it comes on the screen. The files exsist, no error's. Config File:

```
<?php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '***';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'DBName';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'DBPass';
 $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://kennemerboeken.nl/phpadmin/';
 $cfg['SendErrorReports']  = 'always';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'DBName';
 $cfg['ServerDefault'] = 'DBName';
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked to see what's in your webserver error logs?

Comment: Check the permission on the PhpMyAdmin files

Comment: Nothing in the error log, the permissions are right.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it is setting the style of the main body tag to "display:none".  This can be fixed by adding the following configuration to the file **config.inc.php** in the path C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14 or whatever your phpmyadmin installation path is.

**$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;**

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyadmin application don't have a log file, but you can perform this trick:
Ih the app folder exists a php script that when executed will return a result with the errors you find.
On Ubuntu Server the file is in:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/error_report.php
```

then you must enter that folder and run

```
php error_report.php
```

this will return the errors that Phpmyadmin has, most of the time they are errors in the configuration file **config.inc.php**